# Erro em reescrita de código procedural para OOP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

O arquivo [`wishlist.php`](https://gist.github.com/Silence00/0c7236aa0176b5043f1a) disponível no GIST deveria, através de métodos do arquivo [`db.php`](https://gist.github.com/Silence00/64399f17777925211a43), realizar ações de *CRUD* e imprimir na tela os resultados obtidos, mas nada é impresso. De mesmo modo o arquivo [`createNewWisher.php`](https://gist.github.com/Silence00/0ec38b8b13839b6bc23b) deveria também realizar operações do tipo, mas a tela fica branca.

O sistema funciona perfeitamente em modo procedural, isso aconteceu quando o adaptei para *OO*. Acredito que esteja deixando algo muito simples passar em branco, e como sou iniciante com programação não estou conseguindo perceber.

### Códigos:

- db.php: https://gist.github.com/Silence00/64399f17777925211a43
- wishlist.php: https://gist.github.com/Silence00/0c7236aa0176b5043f1a
- createNewWisher: https://gist.github.com/Silence00/0ec38b8b13839b6bc23b

Comment: Coloque no arquivo onde a tela fica em branco isso no inicio:
`ini_set('display_error', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @rray inseri, mas nenhum erro foi informado.

Comment: @rray a página não está carregando nem o formulário; como se não houvesse nenhum código na página. Quando eu retiro do script o require e o `$wisherID = WishDB:: ...` o formulário funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tela em branco é uma indição de que algum erro aconteceu e o servidor normalmente o de produção oculta os erros por questão de segurança. Para conserto ou debug rápido em produção basta adicionar duas linhas uma que exibe os erros e a outra que indica quais deles devem ser mostrados.
Mais informações sobre erros veja no [wiki do php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).

```
ini_set('display_error', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Testei o seu código de listagem e ela apresentou os seguintes erros na classe `db`

> Fatal error: Cannot override final method PDO::__wakeup()

Esse é um método mágico e **[final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php)** que não pode ser sobreescrito, logo comenta ou remova ela.

> Fatal error: Access level to WishDB::__construct() must be public (as
>   in class PDO) in

Como a classe `db` herda de `PDO` você não pode diminuir o nível de acesso um método/propriedade da classe pai. Como o erro sugere deixe o construtor de `db`como público.

```
class WishDB extends PDO{
   //propriedades omitidas
   private function __construct(){
```

O resultado da listagem não pode ser obtido por que seu método retorna um boolean(retorno de `execute()` ao invés de um array. No caso adicione o tratamento de erro e um array

```
public function getWishesByWisherId($wisherID)
{
    $consult = $this->prepare("SELECT `id`, `description`, `due_date` FROM `wishes` WHERE `wisherid`=:wisherid");
    $consult->bindValue(':wisherid', $wisherID);
    return $consult->execute();
}
```

Remova o `return $consult->execute();` conforme o código abaixo.

```
    if($consult->execute() === false){
        print_r($consult->errorInfo());
    }
```

No arquivo de listagem, mude:

```
$result = WishDB::getInstance()->getWishesByWisherId($wisherID);
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

por:

```
$result = WishDB::getInstance()->getWishesByWisherId($wisherID);
foreach($result as $row)
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!! Obrigado também pela dica!

Comment: De nada quando precisar, resolveu tudo? não testei a parte do insert. @Luan.

Comment: Consegui arrumar; com as dicas que você me deu consegui ver alguns outros erros. Obrigado!